# Regular Expression to replace iframe src - preg_replace based on size

Tags: php, regex, iframe, curl

Im using a piratebay reverse proxy script that uses curl to load the thepiratebay. It also has an option to remove/replace the ads but it's using str_replace and i was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Here is how the current script removes unwanted content

```
<?php
function remove_bloat($toremove){
include("configurationfile.php");

//Fix /static links so they work in subdirs
$toremove = str_replace("src=\"/static","src=\"static" , $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace("href=\"/static","href=\"static" , $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace("url(\"/static","url(\"static" , $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace("url('/static","url('static" , $toremove);

$toremove = str_replace("//static.thepiratebay.se/","static/" , $toremove);

//Remove Ads

$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/exo_na/center.html" width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $leaderboard, $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/exo_na/center.html" width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $leaderboard, $toremove);

$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/exo_na/sky2.html" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="padding-top: 100px"></iframe>', $rightside, $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/exo_na/sky2.html" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="padding-top: 100px"></iframe>', $rightside, $toremove);

$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/exo_na/sky1.html" width="120" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $leftside, $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/exo_na/sky1.html" width="120" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $leftside, $toremove);

$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/exo_na/bottom.html" width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $leaderboard, $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/exo_na/bottom.html" width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $leaderboard, $toremove);

$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/exo_na/top.html" width="468" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $topsmall, $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace('<iframe src="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/exo_na/top.html" width="468" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', $topsmall, $toremove);

$toremove = str_replace('sessionHash', '', $toremove);
$toremove = str_replace('baypops.com', '', $toremove);

return $toremove;
}
```

the str_replace used to just remove the ads but i created my own variables and added them in which now replaces the ads with my own content. ($leaderboard, $leftside, $rightside, $topsmall)

But i have found more ads that are loaded through curl and would like to replace them as well, the problem is that this set of ads do not have static URLs and have the page title as a variable in all the iframe sources as shown below...

```
<iframe src="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/ividi/ividi.php?b=top&n=This_Is_the_End_%282013%29_720p_BrRip_x264_-_YIFY" width="469" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

same ad location different page

```
<iframe src="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/ividi/ividi.php?b=top&n=Jobs_2013_HDRip_x264_AC3-JYK" width="469" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

again same ad different page

```
 <iframe src="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/ividi/ividi.php?b=top&n=World_War_Z_%282013%29_UNRATED_1080p_BrRip_x264_-_YIFY" width="469" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You can see the only thing that changes is the sub url cdn and the end part of the src.

So i was thinking of using preg_replace instead of str_replace and try and use a regular expression just for the iframe src and replace based on the width and height.

So something along the lines of the following

```
$toremove = preg_replace('<iframe src="/regular expression ?/" width="469" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>', 'replaced content', $toremove);
```

Would this work as well as how can i use a regex just for the src ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$toremove = preg_replace('~<iframe src="http://cdn[0-9]+\.adexprt\.com[^"]+" width="469" height="60" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>~', 'replaced content', $toremove);
```

`[^"]+` matches all characters except double quotes.

EDIT:

I forgot about the delimiters. I placed `~` in between the single quotes and the first and last characters in the regex pattern.

Comment: What about if the ad is loaded using cdn1 and not cdn2 ?

Comment: @Analog Sorry, I didn't catch that difference. How about now?

Comment: unfortunately when i use the above code it just breaks the page without any error messages shown. I thought it might just be because im using preg_replace for some reason so i tried just changing one of the original str_replace to preg_replace while leaving everything else on the line the same to see if that also broke the page and it did. But then to double check i used the following preg_replace which did work but it's a simpler regex set to remove the whole iframe which is not my intention  $toremove = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?>/', '', $toremove);

Comment: @Analog Oh, oops, I forgot something important as well. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Perfect, with that last change it's working just how i need it. THANKS

Comment: @Analog You can now remove all the ads from `adexprt` with a single regex :D You're welcome!

Comment: I didn't even think of that! I've just replace all the old str_replace with the new preg_replace and it's working perfectly.